# How to update read status of an email using MS Graph Api

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use python and MS Graph Api to read emails from outlook.
My intention is to create ticket object in our CRM application whenever any email comes.
So, my application is to monitor the mailbox to see if any mails are staying unread.
I am able to successfully login and read all unseen email from outlook.
But emails are not getting marked as "read" email even though read by my program. it is shown as unread and that
causes to create duplicate tickets in my application.
is there any way to mark as read once we read by API call?
Please see the python code I am using

```
read_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{}/messages'.format(
            self.userId)
#user id will be given 

response = requests.get(read_url,
     
                                headers={ 

 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + self.result['access_token']})
```

#token will be generated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a property isRead on each email. This means You have to update each email Your app process with PATCH request and isRead set to true.

You can find more info in official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)